# Cook Levin reduction, if L∈NP and it it is known that φaccept=true

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, turing-machines

I encountered a question in a test I have taken, its was Proof or Disprove question.

Let L∈NP and let Fcl be the Boolean expression that was created by Cook Levin reduction.

It is known that for all X, X∈L <==> Fcl∈SAT.

Now remember φaccept that Cook Levin reduction produce which is part of Fcl.

the claim you need to decide if its true and supply Proof for it or Disprove and supply counter example is:

φaccept=true **if and only if** in the last configuration in the configuration table that describes the calculation of the Turing machine M on the language L and the input X,W is in Qaccept.

the course books are:

1) T. H. Cormen, C. E. Leiserson, R. L. Rivest and C. Stein, Introduction to Algorithms,2nd edition.

2) J. Kleinberg and E. Tardos, Algorithm Design

[Cook Levin Reduction](http://courses.cs.tau.ac.il/cc/12a/pdf/CookLevin.pdf)

Thank you very much !

Comment: This question seems to depend on precise details on how a specific implementation of the Cook-Levin construction is presented. Those details are generally something each author of a textbook or lecture notes will decide for himself as what he think is the clearest way to express the _underlying idea_. So without a much more detailed reference to what you're looking at, we can't know exactly what the $\varphi_{\rm accept}$ you're talking about is. It sure sounds like it would be likely to refer to something with the property you describe, though.

Comment: the course books are:

1) T. H. Cormen, C. E. Leiserson, R. L. Rivest and C. Stein, Introduction to Algorithms,2nd edition.


2) J. Kleinberg and E. Tardos, Algorithm Design.

Comment: And in which of those books do you find an explanation of what "$\varphi_{\rm accept}$" is?

Comment: this is the reduction:
http://courses.cs.tau.ac.il/cc/12a/pdf/CookLevin.pdf

Comment: x @hagaip: In that case, **hint:** "$\phi_{\rm accept}=$true" does not tell you anything about whether, say, $\phi_{\rm move}$ is true.

Comment: but if L∈NP so  ϕmove and the others are for sure true arent they?

Comment: x @hagaip: Why would they be? Their value depends on the truth values of the variables in the Boolean expression the reduction produces, and the only thing you're assuming about those truth values is that they happen to make $\phi_{\rm accept}$ true.